# Django Rest Framework have a to_representation on a foreignKey with source

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a nested relation on a key that has a different name from the name that the key in the DB has.
I am able to do both, just not if they are combined.

I need the api name to be `countryOfOrigin` and the source is `country_of_origin`.

However the only I get to work is either

```
[
  {
    "articleIdOwn": "1234abc",
    "articleNameOwn": "1234abc",
    "countryOfOrigin": "DE"
  }
]
```

where the serializer looks like this:

```py
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    articleIdOwn = serializers.CharField(source='article_id_own')
    articleNameOwn = serializers.CharField(source='article_name_own')
    countryOfOrigin = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='country_of_origin', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User_Product
        fields = ['articleIdOwn', 'articleNameOwn','countryOfOrigin']
```

Or this:

```
[
  {
    "articleIdOwn": "1234abc",
    "articleNameOwn": "1234abc",
    "country_of_origin": {
      "isoCode": "DE",
      "country": "Deutschland"
    }
  }
]
```

where the serializer looks like this:

```py
class HS_CountriesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    isoCode = serializers.CharField(source='iso_code', read_only=True)
    country = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = HS_Countries
        fields = ['isoCode', 'country']

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    articleIdOwn = serializers.CharField(source='article_id_own')
    articleNameOwn = serializers.CharField(source='article_name_own')

    class Meta:
        model = User_Product
        fields = ['articleIdOwn', 'articleNameOwn', 'country_of_origin']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        self.fields['country_of_origin'] = HS_CountriesSerializer(read_only=True)
        return super().to_representation(instance)
```

I however want it to look like this:

```
[
  {
    "articleIdOwn": "1234abc",
    "articleNameOwn": "1234abc",
    "countryOfOrigin": {
      "isoCode": "DE",
      "country": "Deutschland"
    }
  }
]
```

The the models of Product and Countries

```py
class User_Product(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    code = models.ForeignKey('HS_Code', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    article_id_own = models.TextField()
    article_name_own = models.TextField()
    country_of_origin = models.ForeignKey(
        'HS_Countries', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

class HS_Countries(models.Model):
    iso_code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=2)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: Show your models for Product and Countries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HS_CountriesSerializer` to get what you want.

```
class HS_CountriesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    isoCode = serializers.CharField(source='iso_code', read_only=True)
    country = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = HS_Countries
        fields = ['isoCode', 'country']

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    articleIdOwn = serializers.CharField(source='article_id_own')
    articleNameOwn = serializers.CharField(source='article_name_own')
    # add the following line and use it in your fields
    countryOfOrigin = HS_CountriesSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User_Product
        fields = ['articleIdOwn', 'articleNameOwn', 'countryOfOrigin']
```

If your objective is to change your fields from snake case to camel case for API then you should use [djangorestframework-camel-case](https://github.com/vbabiy/djangorestframework-camel-case), this will help you in avoiding rewriting fields in serializer just to change the case of fields.

After you have installed the djangorestframework-camel-case, you can do the following:

```
class HS_CountriesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = HS_Countries
        fields = ['iso_code', 'country']

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country_of_origin = HS_CountriesSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User_Product
        fields = ['article_id_own', 'article_name_own', 'country_of_origin']
```

Comment: Hey, I added the two models.

Comment: Ohh and when I do it as suggested. The key `countryOfOrigin` isnt returned in the response.